# inconsistent behaviour for pandas idxmax(idxmin) method with pd.NaT

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I upgraded pandas to version 1.3.3. And discovered that DataFrame.idxmax is raising ValueError when the row consists of pd.NaT

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan], 'b': [np.nan]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [pd.NaT], 'b': [pd.NaT]})
print(df1.idxmax(axis=1)) # np.NaN as expected
print(df2.idxmax(axis=1)) # ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence
```

But `df2.idxmax(axis=1)` returns `np.nan` as I expect when I use [pandas 1.2.4](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.4/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html).
Which has the same documentation as the [current version](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html). Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Comment: This is likely because `NaT` or `pd.NA` are still experimental features and not handled by all functions

Comment: btw, I was able to bypass this issue by changing the part of the script where I use idxmax to find a column name with max value. From `df['max_column'] = df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)` to `df['max_column'] = df[cols].dropna(how='all').idxmax(axis=1)`. In case someone has the same issue.

Comment: Looks like an issue with the argmax code changing between 1.2.4 and 1.3.3. Previously in 1.2.4 this case would be properly handled by `nanops.nanargmax(self._values)`, but now it gets delgated to `self._values.argmax()` which clearly can't handle a case of all `NaN` for ExtensionArrays. Looks like their logic block in [line 640](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.3.3/pandas/core/base.py#L640) needs to also have a clause for `or delegate.isna().all()`. I'd open a bug report, clearly something isn't working as it should.